# Computer causes other devices to lose internet access

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

I recently moved into a new apartment and as a result got a new ISP and router.
Quite quickly I noticed I was having a strange issue that I'd never seen before.

When my computer connects to the network, after an arbitrary amount of time it loses the ability to actually connect to the internet.
The connection is still there in theory, but I can't ping anything (including the router, I'm pretty sure).
 What's even stranger is that after yet another seemingly arbitrary period of time, all my other devices also lose the ability to connect to the internet (my phone and Chromecast both say "Connected, no internet").

Everything gets fixed on all the devices the second I restart my computer, but sometimes it also comes back to normal without a reboot after an arbitrary amount of time.

I use Linux Mint ([here](https://pastebin.com/H0qYxsuT)'s the output of `inxi -Fxxxrz`).

I tried booting my laptop into a clean image of the system from a USB and in that case everything seemed fine (although this test wasn't 100% conclusive, since maybe I didn't wait long enough for the issue to occur - sometimes it takes an hour and sometimes over a day).
 I also booted the laptop into Windows and no issues occurred there either, so I'm inclined to think something has to be wrong with my Linux setup.

Whenever the connection on my laptop stops working, according to the admin panel of my router, the laptop is still connected.
 My ISP also claims there is nothing wrong with the network on their end.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be happening and what in my setup might be causing this?
 Also, what commands should I run to diagnose the root of the problem?

EDIT: Adding `route -n` output.

The routing table when everything is fine:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 virbr0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

The routing table when it's not:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    20600  0        0 wlo1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 virbr0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

Comment: Check your IP address, the subnet and the gateway. Do they differ between when you have internet access and when you don't?

Comment: @tkausl Yes, the IP stays the same (192.168.1.15). The gateway as well (192.168.1.1, which is the IP of my router). Is the subnet the `netmask` part of `ifconfig`? If so, then that also stays the same (255.255.255.0).

Comment: What error message do you get when trying to ping the router in such cases? Have you tried traceroute?

Comment: The one difference I've noticed is when I do `ip route`. When the connection goes bad, the first line says `default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 20600`, and when everything is fine, this line ends with `metric 600`. Not sure what this metric is, though.

Comment: @tkausl Pinging the router results in `From 192.168.1.15 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable`. I haven't tried traceroute yet.

Comment: Please add to your post the routing tables when all is fine and when the problem occured.

Comment: @harrymc I saved the output of `route -n` in both scenarios. Added it to the post. Looks like the metric value is the only difference. Not sure if it's the cause or a symptom of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar weird issue. After a prolonged troubleshooting it transpired the issue was with the router password for wifi. I had added in a special character to the default account password and for some reason it was causing issues periodically. Since changing the password to only letters and digits this hasn't occurred again.

Comment: At this point, I'm willing to try anything, so I'll definitely give this a try :) I do have a crazy long password with lots of special characters in it, so who knows.

Comment: That unfortunately did not do the trick for me.